# PHP: =0D, =A20 symbols

Tags: php

After obtaining info from an email body, I have a lot of symbols such as =0D, =A20, etc... How can I remove them? I do not want to use

```
$body = str_replace('=A20', '', $body);
```

because if the email body actually contains that it will be replaced.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example string with those symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't replace them to nothing - thoose characters aren't nothing, they are part of the text.

E-mail messages aren't plain text, they are [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding). Thoose examples are part of the [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, which you can identify by the

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

line at the beginning of the e-mail message.

And [php has a method to decode it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php)